# CSS: scale float div width 100% until 2 float divs of min-width can fit the width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having some trouble with CSS as I don't use it regularly. The problem is the following: I have multiple float objects of the same size. To keep the design responsive a smartphone might display these float objects vertically. On a larger screen though, the float objects might be displayed next to one another.

To maximize the visibility on a smartphone the float objects should take up all of the width (100%). I added a min-width and max-width. The max-width is 2 times the min-width. We start off by having the float objects vertically aligned. When the horizontal screen size increases, the width of the objects fill the screen but as soon as the object reaches the max-width it should display 2 of those float objects next to another with min-width, and so on. Any idea on how to do this exactly?

Thank you so much!

Comment: would flexbox model be an option for you ? any how, do not forget to provide the html structure and css you tried so far. My cristal ball broke into pieces

Comment: @GCyrillus I thought about that but came to the conclusion it would be clearer by just explaining the problem. The code contains a lot more that does not have anything to do with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no code to use , here a simple example with flex and min-width:

With 3 children at `min-width:300px`, here we have a break point at 900px, then at 600px, then body will show a scrollbar beloww 300px width. *mediaqueries are unnecessary here* .

```css
body /* or whatever container you use */{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
div {
  flex:1;
  min-width:300px;/* first  break point at 300px x number of divs */
  background:turquoise;
}
div + div {
  background:tomato;
}
div:last-of-type {
  background:gold;
}
```

```html
<div>one</div>
<div>two</div>
<div>three</div>
```

[codepen to play with](http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/MyRZxR)

Comment: Looks like the thing I'm searching for! Thanks again